# Iterating an associative array (key/value pair) in javascript with jQuery, where the values are jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, key-value

I have an associative array which has a string-based key, and a jQuery object as the value. That object may contain more than one jQuery objects itself. Since this is an associated array, I should be able to iterate through it with code like the following.

```
$.each(array_name, function(key, value){
  // Code to actually do something here
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't actually iterate through the array at all. I notice that the length of the array is 0, despite containing objects. Short of making this an indexed array, and maintaining the index myself, I don't see what else to do. What am I doing wrong?

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D36AQ/) to illustrate what I am doing.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/n2LSs/ You can just use an object.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have associative arrays. It has arrays and objects.

Comment: That is not an array, hence it does not have a length property.

Comment: I've spent too much time working with php... Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

An object should be declared as `{}`

```
var test = {}
```

Changing that seems to fix the issue.

Comment: That was it. I simply forgot that this needs to be structured as an Object, and not an array.